# how statsmodels linear regression model calculate out std error of coefficients?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

as you know, statsmodels can print out summary after OLS fit. Following picture will show its output. 
[image: statsmodel summary output]
My question is:
how statsmodels can calculate out std err for all the coefs? As i understand, std err describe mean deviation for values to its mean, but here, we can not know its mean, and even no other values(except the exact one value for each coef), so no way to calculate the std err...
Can you give me some hint on how does this work and calculated out the std err value?

Comment: in OLS, the variance of the regession is calculated as $$Var(\beta\hat)=\sigma^2(X^TX)^{−1}$$ - no latex on SO.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Large_sample_properties

Comment: @modesitt, what is the $\sigma$ here, and how to calculate it? Can you give a little explaination on why that work?